# ag-grid: hover row style not working, when cell background overrides

Tags: ag-grid-angular

I am changing the background color of cells on some conditions in cellstyle

```
    if(//some condition)   
    {
    //highlighted the background color
      return { 'background-color': '#8a1538', color: 'white' };
    }

//otherwise clear the highlighted color and return default colors for grid
    if (params.node.rowIndex % 2 === 0)
      return { 'background-color': '#f9f8f8', color: '#333f48' };
    else
      return { 'background-color': '#fff', color: '#333f48' };
```

But after this, hover functionally is not working, how can the hover row will work?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like this might help:

```
  div.ag-row-hover:not(.ag-row-group) div{
    background: #52a8ff !important;
    color: white;
  }

  div.ag-row-hover .ag-cell-inline-editing div {
    color: black;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **cellClassRules** as mentioned [here](https://thinkster.io/tutorials/using-ag-grid-with-react-styling/cell-styling) :

```
cellClassRules: {
  "ag-red": (params) => {
    return params.value <= 100;
  },
    "ag-amber": (params) => {
    return params.value > 100 && params.value <= 200;
  },
    "ag-green": (params) => {
     return params.value > 700;
   },  
}
```